Reinstall MongoDB in my reinstalled Windows
My Windows PC ran into problems a few days ago and I reinstalled it.
Now, I need to reinstall MongoDB. However, I forgot whether I installed my previous MongoDB in C drive or E drive. Currently, E drive has a mongo folder (E:\mongo\), which has folders such as bin, data, log, and mongodb-databse-tools, and files such as LICENSE-Community. My first question: does this indicate that I previously installed MongoDB in E drive?
If the answer to my first question is Yes, what is the best practice to reinstall MongoDB? Can I set the installation folder to E:\mongo\? Is this recommended? My concern is that this will overwrite my previous data files in the data folder.
Any help is appreciated!

Not clear what you are looking for. The MongoDB binaries can be installed in default location, usually c:\Program Files\MonogoDB\ or similar.
However, the folder containing your data should be somewhere else. When you install the MongoDB service, then it is done like this:
mongod.exe --config e:\MongoDB\config\mongod.cfg --install

And your config file e:\MongoDB\config\mongod.cfg may look like this:
# where to store your data
storage:
  dbPath: e:\MongoDB\data

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path:  e:\MongoDB\log\mongod.log

# Windows process management
processManagement:
  windowsService:
    serviceName: MongoDB
    displayName: MongoDB
    description: MongoDB Server

If you don't specify any data folder, then C:\data\db will be used.
Don't be afraid, the MongoDB setup does not create or overwrite any data folder. It's actually a common problem that MongoDB does not start, because data folder does not exist - you an find many questions for that here on SO.
See also What is the default database path for MongoDB?
